# HTML File Select Specific File Within Directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, file, upload

Is it possible to program an HTML file input to select a specific file within a directory or volume.

When the file input button is clicked, the file selector is opened, and the user selects a folder or a thumb drive. Then in jQuery a specific file is selected within the chosen directory.

For example, the user selects a thumb drive in the file selector, and then when the form is submitted, only a specific (hidden) file is uploaded.

Comment: think of how stupidly bad this would be... allowing joe-random website to specify files to be uploaded from a user's machine... what's to stop a malicious site from grabbing your /etc/password or c:\windows\system32\config\SAM?

Comment: Actually the purpose is s users can turn a thumb drive into a login key.

Comment: Hope your concept is not explained detailed in your question. You have to improve your question with Why? and where it going to be applied?.....

Answer (score 5):

No, for security reasons, this isn't possible.